# Cannot include a static library in the project

Tags: visual-studio-2005, lnk2019

I am developing a subproject in a solution in MS Visual Studio 2005. The subproject is a Windows CE 6.0 service (as DLL) and it is included in the Windows CE 6.0 OS Project. In the subproject I need to use some functions from "ceosutil.lib" (svsutil.hxx is the header), but I cannot link it to my subproject. When building, I get the following type of errors: "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol".

What is interesting, when I switch the project type to a static library, it compiles without problems. If I start a new DLL project (standalone one, not as subproject), it also works (the "ceosutil.lib" is already listed in the Additional Dependencies of the project and all configurations).

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer to my own question. The solution is to add the name of the library ("ceosutil.lib", after a space) to Additional Libraries field in the Link tab of the subproject properties:

In MS Visual Studio 2005:
Right Mouse Click on subproject name -> Properties -> Link tab -> Additional Libraries.

default value was: `$(_PROJECTROOT)\cesysgen\sdk\lib\$(_CPUINDPATH)\coredll.lib`

new value: `$(_PROJECTROOT)\cesysgen\sdk\lib\$(_CPUINDPATH)\coredll.lib ceosutil.lib`

Update:
It is even easier to open the subproject (right mouse btn -> open) and paste the path to the library in the TARGETLIBS section. The result will be exactly the same:

TARGETLIBS= \
    $(_PROJECTROOT)\cesysgen\sdk\lib\$(_CPUINDPATH)\coredll.lib \